# pip install sklearn openmp

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to install scikit-learn using `pip install sklearn` and deriviates like `pip install -U scitkit-learn`. But everytime I get this error

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'd:\users\woute\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\woute\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ldcm020y\\scikit-learn\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\woute\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ldcm020y\\scikit-learn\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5ymvhxj1\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ldcm020y\scikit-learn\
    Complete output (48 lines):
    Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include /Tctest_openmp.c /Foobjects\test_openmp.obj /openmp
    test_openmp.c
    test_openmp.c(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ldcm020y\scikit-learn\setup.py", line 290, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ldcm020y\scikit-learn\setup.py", line 286, 
      ...
      ...
      File "C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ldcm020y\scikit-learn\sklearn\_build_utils\openmp_helpers.py", line 140, in check_openmp_support
        raise CompileError(err_message)
    distutils.errors.CompileError:
                        ***

    It seems that scikit-learn cannot be built with OpenMP support.

    - Make sure you have followed the installation instructions:

        https://scikit-learn.org/dev/developers/advanced_installation.html

    - If your compiler supports OpenMP but the build still fails, please
      submit a bug report at:

        https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues

    - If you want to build scikit-learn without OpenMP support, you can set
      the environment variable SKLEARN_NO_OPENMP and rerun the build
      command. Note however that some estimators will run in sequential
      mode and their `n_jobs` parameter will have no effect anymore.

                        ***

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'd:\users\woute\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\woute\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ldcm020y\\scikit-learn\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\woute\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ldcm020y\\scikit-learn\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\woute\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5ymvhxj1\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I've installed numpy and pandas correctly. Some people also had this problem but only one single linux solution was proposed.

Comment: Which version of python are you using? I had the same problem weeks ago and it turned out the version of python I was using wasn't compatible with sklearn, so I had to downgrade it

Comment: 3.8, should I try 3.7?

Comment: Yes..That was exactly my problem. Python 3.8 is not stable yet, so some libraries doesn't work properly. Try it again with 3.7

Answer (score 4):

- Downgrading to Python 3.7 does the trick !
- It seems that there is no compatibility yet for python 3.8 .

There's actually a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/14624) opened for the same on sci-kit learn's page.